# Why is my table distributed over multiple filegroups (no partitions)?

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server 2016 database (web edition) is split up into the following files (Appendix: SQL query 1):
[image: MYDB database files]

As you can see there are two filegroups defined: *PRIMARY* and *DataFG*

The table CarInsuranceLog is placed into the filegroup DataFG as can be seen here (Appendix: SQL query 2):

[image: Table and filegroup information]

After dropping the table CarInsuranceLog with `DROP TABLE dbo.CarInsuranceLog` I would have assumed that only the available space in filegroup DataFG would have changed. But as you can see in the next picture the space in both filegroups (PRIMARY and DataFG) was affected:

[image: MYDB database files after drop]

There was only one (clustered) index on the table and there is no partitioning.

Therefore my question is how is it even possible that space in both filegroups is affected even though there is only one index in one filegroup?

**Appendix SQL Queries**

```
--SQL Query 1
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT FG          = fg.name, 
         FileID      = f.file_id,
         LogicalName = f.name,
         [Path]      = f.physical_name, 
         FileSizeMB  = f.size/128.0, 
         UsedSpaceMB = CONVERT(bigint, FILEPROPERTY(f.[name], 'SpaceUsed'))/128.0, 
         GrowthMB    = CASE f.is_percent_growth WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE f.growth/128.0 END,
         MaxSizeMB   = NULLIF(f.max_size, -1)/128.0,
         DriveSizeMB = vs.total_bytes/1048576.0,
         DriveFreeMB = vs.available_bytes/1048576.0
  FROM sys.database_files AS f
  INNER JOIN sys.filegroups AS fg
        ON f.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(DB_ID(), f.file_id) AS vs
)
SELECT 
    [Filegroup] = FG, 
    FileID, 
    LogicalName,
    [Path],
    FileSizeMB  = CONVERT(decimal(18,2), FileSizeMB),
    FreeSpaceMB = CONVERT(decimal(18,2), FileSizeMB-UsedSpaceMB),
    [FreeSpace %]         = CONVERT(decimal(5,2), 100.0*(FileSizeMB-UsedSpaceMB)/FileSizeMB),
    DriveSizeMB = CONVERT(bigint, DriveSizeMB),
    DriveFreeMB = CONVERT(bigint, DriveFreeMB)
FROM src
ORDER BY FG, LogicalName;

--SQL Query 2
SELECT 
    o.[name] ObjectName, 
    o.[type] ObjectType, 
    i.[name] IndexName, 
    i.[index_id] IndexId, 
    f.[name] FileGroupName
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.filegroups f
    ON i.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects o
    ON i.[object_id] = o.[object_id] 
    AND i.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
WHERE 
    o.type = 'U' -- User Created Tables
    AND o.[name] = 'CarInsuranceLog'
ORDER BY o.name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is that the table has LOB columns (`varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)`), created on the `PRIMARY` filegroup (using the `TEXTIMAGE_ON` clause).

Your query 2 misses LOB allocations, as you can see from the example below.

```
CREATE DATABASE Olf
ON PRIMARY
 (NAME = OlfData1, FILENAME = 'C:\DemoDatabases\DbFiles\a\OlfData1.mdf', SIZE = 20MB, MAXSIZE = 500MB, FILEGROWTH = 5MB)
,(NAME = OlfData2, FILENAME = 'C:\DemoDatabases\DbFiles\a\OlfData2.ndf', SIZE = 20MB, MAXSIZE = 500MB, FILEGROWTH = 5MB)
,FILEGROUP HistoryData
 (NAME = N'OlfHist1',FILENAME = N'C:\DemoDatabases\DbFiles\a\OlfHist1.ndf' ,  SIZE = 5MB, FILEGROWTH = 10MB )
LOG ON
(NAME = OlfLog1, FILENAME = 'C:\DemoDatabases\DbFiles\a\OlfLog1.ldf', SIZE = 10MB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 5MB )
GO

USE Olf
GO

CREATE TABLE t(c1 int, c2 nvarchar(max))
TEXTIMAGE_ON HistoryData
GO

--Insert a bunch of rows
INSERT INTO t
SELECT TOP(1000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), REPLICATE(CAST(N'x' AS nvarchar(max)), 50000)
FROM sys.columns AS a, sys.columns AS b
```

Your query 2, gives us this result:

```
ObjectName  ObjectType  IndexName   IndexId FileGroupName
t           U           NULL        0       PRIMARY
```

Compare that to a query extracted from my sp_indexinfo. I grabbed the space allocation part of that procedure and posted that query below. (You can find the procedure here: https://karaszi.com/spindexinfo-enhanced-index-information-procedure).

```
tbl_name    type    pages   MB      location
t           heap    13513   105.57  HistoryData
t           heap    9       0.07    PRIMARY
```

Note how your query 2 misses the allocations done on the HistoryData filegroup, where my query includes those allocations.

Here's the query I ran to get the above result:

```
WITH
 key_columns AS 
( 
    SELECT 
     c.OBJECT_ID 
    ,c.name AS column_name 
    ,ic.key_ordinal 
    ,ic.is_included_column 
    ,ic.index_id 
    ,ic.is_descending_key 
    FROM sys.columns AS c 
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic ON c.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID AND ic.column_id = c.column_id 
) 
,physical_info AS 
( 
    SELECT p.OBJECT_ID, p.index_id, p.data_compression_desc, ds.name AS location, SUM(CASE WHEN a.type_desc = 'IN_ROW_DATA' THEN p.rows ELSE 0 END) AS rows, SUM(a.total_pages) AS pages 
    FROM sys.partitions AS p 
    INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units AS a ON p.hobt_id = a.container_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS ds ON a.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id 
    GROUP BY OBJECT_ID, index_id, p.data_compression_desc, ds.name 
) 
SELECT 
 OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID)                       AS tbl_name 
,CASE i.TYPE 
  WHEN 0 THEN 'heap' 
  WHEN 1 THEN 'cl' 
  WHEN 2 THEN 'nc' 
  WHEN 3 THEN 'xml' 
  WHEN 5 THEN 'cl cs' 
  WHEN 6 THEN 'nc cs' 
  ELSE CAST(i.TYPE AS VARCHAR(2)) 
END                                             AS type 
,p.pages 
,CAST((p.pages * 8.00) / 1024 AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS MB 
,CASE WHEN i.is_disabled = 1 THEN '[DISABLED]' ELSE p.location END AS location   
FROM sys.indexes AS i 
LEFT OUTER JOIN physical_info AS p 
  ON i.OBJECT_ID = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS s 
  ON s.OBJECT_ID = i.OBJECT_ID AND s.index_id = i.index_id AND s.database_id = DB_ID() 
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(i.OBJECT_ID, 'IsMsShipped') = 0 
AND OBJECTPROPERTY(i.OBJECT_ID, 'IsTableFunction') = 0 
AND OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) = 't'
ORDER BY tbl_name
```

Comment: Tibor, you nailed it. Any idea how to migrate those columns to the second filegroup?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Hans. I tried a couple of things to move the textimage data, but I didn't find anything useful. So far, a table re-create is that I can see. But I might be missing something obvious. I suggest you create a new item here at SE, for that exact topic (move textimage to a new filegroup) to be as focused as possible. Feel free to throw in my T-SQL code above so people can easily create such a setup and have something to try on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tibor, appreciate your effort. I too came to the conclusion that a recreate is the only way to go. Having a live system 24/7 doesn't make that easier though. I think I will reuse my migration scripts that I created for a int->bigint live migration once. I remember the tricky part was the foreign key aware migration to tackle.